# Microsoft Access - Maximum of two columns in Query Design

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, max, calculation

I want to create three additional calculated columns:

- Max 2022/10 (Maximum of FC 2022/10, OB 2022/10)
- Max 2022/11 (Maximum of FC 2022/11, OB 2022/11)
- Max 2022/12 (Maximum of FC 2022/12, OB 2022/12)

How can I do this in MS Access using the Query Design View?

[image: The Columns]

Edit:
Here is my query design:
[image: Query Desgin]

Here is some sample data:
[image]

Comment: In design view, you can use a subquery, or create another query and join.  Can you share your table design and possibly some sample data?  Not sure i fully understand the question.  Querying the max results and saying `max result 1 & "," & max result 2`

Comment: Sample data and desired result should be provided as text tables and/or SQL to create table and populate with data, not images. That is your actual raw table structure? What does Q4 indicate - calendar quarter? You have a table for each quarter? None of this is a normalized structure.